# Maven assembly plugin attach sources of dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Some open source license require to distribute the original code for each dependency. I need to make the extracted sources available to my maven assembly plugin.

How to recursively get all the source-JARs for every single dependency used?

`dependency:sources` does only download source-dependencies to the local Maven repo, and not to a custom directory that I need to define.

Comment: This is not possible. What if you depend on a proprietary library that whose code is not public?

Comment: Of course this would not work if the sources are not available via maven. But most of them are. As I stated in my post I am only talking about open source components.

Comment: By the way, [`dependency:sources`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html) resolves the sources for all dependencies of your project (including transitive ones). So Im not sure why you're saying it isn't recursive.

Comment: the goal you mentioned has a parameter "outputFile" - does that not do what you need it to do? see: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html#outputFile

Comment: No it does not, OutputFile specifies some kind of logFILE not a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

```
                   <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>get-dependency-sources</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${sources.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <classifier>sources</classifier>
                                    <prependGroupId>true</prependGroupId>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

in combination with

```
               <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack-sources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <move todir="${sources.directory}">
                                          <fileset dir="${sources.directory}">
                                            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                                        </fileset>
                                        <mapper type="glob" from="*.jar" to="*.zip"/>
                                    </move>
                                </target>

                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        ...
```

First collects all resources within `${sources.directory}` and then renames the jars to zip files (which enables a "normal" user to view their contents in Windows Explorer.
Alternatively you can also directly unzip the jars using the `unzip` ANT task.